# Using devise I would like to save some value from old session into the new session upon logout

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is the content of my session:

```
Session:
{
 "session_id"=>"0aee1c4fbb70c027099958aea9c06ddc",
 "should_activate_backbone"=>true, 
 "return_to"=>"/",
 "split"=>{"login_signup"=>"New"},   
 "_csrf_token"=>"xY/pVjP0Q2aQVbKO0WiEwkgmadEWOnV9n9EKvM+jJh4="
}
```

I am doing AB testing with split. Therefore If the user logs out I want to keep the variant.
So in the new session I need to put back this part of the old session:

```
"split"=>{"login_signup"=>"New"}
```

And I would like to do that somehow in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reset the value in the new session using after_filter

```
class Authentication::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  after_filter :set_back_experiments, :only => [:destroy]
  def destroy
    @split = session[:split]
    super
  end
private

  def set_back_experiments
    session[:split] = @split
  end
end
```